# How to combine two different outputs in a single output?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question based on a suicide dataset that I am practicing with: which year saw the highest and lowest number of suicides?

To find the year with the highest number of suicides, I used this code:

```
df.groupby('year').suicides_no.sum().sort_values(ascending = False).head(1)
```

To find the year with the lowest number of suicides, I used this code:

```
df.groupby('year').suicides_no.sum().sort_values(ascending = True).head(1)
```

Now, I want to combine both results to get the year with the highest and lowest number of suicides in a single output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this..

```py
suicides_by_year = df.groupby('year').suicides_no.sum()
highest_year = suicides_by_year.idxmax()
lowest_year = suicides_by_year.idxmin()
print(f"Highest year: {highest_year}, Lowest year: {lowest_year}")
```

Answer (score 2):

You cn do it this way:

```
suicides_by_year = df.groupby('year').suicides_no.sum()

highest_year = suicides_by_year.nlargest(1)
lowest_year = suicides_by_year.nsmallest(1)

result = pd.concat([highest_year, lowest_year])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html)
[`Series.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) in [`Series.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.aggregate.html):

```
s = (df.groupby('year').suicides_no.sum()
      .agg(['idxmax','idxmin'])
      .rename({'idxmax':'Max Year',
               'idxmin':'Min Year'}))
```

If need also values:

```
s = df.groupby('year').suicides_no.sum().agg(['idxmax','max','idxmin', 'min'])
```